# Reading HttpRequest Body in REST WCF

Tags: json, web-services, .net-4.0, httprequest, wcf-rest

I got a REST WCF Service running in .net 4 and I've tested the web service it is working and accepting HttpRequest I make to it. But I ran into a problem trying to access the HttpRequest body within the web service. I've tried sending random sizes of data appended on the HttpRequest using both Fiddler and my WinForm app and I can't seem to find any objects in runtime where I can find my request body is located. My initial instinct was to look in the `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream` but the length of that property is 0, so I tried looking in `IncomingWebRequestContext` that object doesn't even have a method nor properties to get the body of the HttpRequest.

So my question is, is there actually a way to access the HttpRequest request body in WCF?

PS:
The data inside the request body is JSON strings and for response it would return the data inside response body as JSON string too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much simpler, this answer on [WCF + REST: Where is the request data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850293/wcf-rest-where-is-the-request-data/1850832#1850832) works fine.

Also, if your request body is deserializable, you can just pass a class. Barring some typos, this should work:

```
public class Banana
{
    public string Colour;
    public int Size;
}
```

...

```
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST", 
    UriTemplate = "bananas", 
    ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string CreateBanana(Banana banana);
```

...

```
public string CreateBanana(Banana banana)
{
    return "It's a " + banana.Colour + " banana!";
}
```

Doing POST with data `{"Colour": "blue", "Size": 5}` to this resource should return `"It's a blue banana!"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `((System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageData)(((System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage)((OperationContext.Current.RequestContext).RequestMessage)).MessageData)).Buffer`

it has type `System.ArraySegment<byte>`

or read [WCF + REST: Where is the request data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850293/wcf-rest-where-is-the-request-data)

Comment: Is this for .Net Framework 4.0? Because I couldn't find BufferedMessageData and BufferedMessage om the System.ServiceModel.Channels namespace

Comment: I used it in debugger (watch window) inside of my .Net Framework 4.0 WCF project.

Comment: I've even went and add the System.ServiceModel reference into my project and I still couldn't locate the BufferedMessageData object inside System.ServiceModel.Channels. I also tried searching it in Object Browser and no result coming back at all.

Comment: You should search in the part "non-public members" in the debugger. If you want to write a code to access the data you should get `System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage` as a instance of `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` type and then access some "non-public members" with the way described in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850293/wcf-rest-where-is-the-request-data.

Comment: `BufferedMessageData` is inaccessible due to its protection level