# What web service to implement so it's easy to read from an iphone application?

Tags: c#, ios, web-services

I want to develop a web service that will enable me to synchronize the databases of my iphone app with a main database.

I will be using c# to write this web service. What kind of web service should I write, and how should it look like for it to be easy to call from the iphone application?

To answer the comment question: I think would prefer XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST webservice with JSON. It will be easier to read from iphone app.  [iPhone interaction with ASP.NET WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290924/iphone-interaction-with-asp-net-webservice)

Also see this for tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/RestWebService.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't go wrong with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx).

It's recommended by microsoft for all web services (outside the MVC world) and supports many different scenarios and interop. For an easier (but more fragile and less versatile) solution you would go with an aspx -> asmx service but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Used RESTful WCF as a web service see this: [WCF REST Service JSON Post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384303/wcf-rest-service-json-post-data)
and this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/RestServiceAPI.aspx?q=wcf+rest+web+service+example

Also used JSON instead of XML tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Also used NSURLConnection but haven't found one very good tutorial yet.