# WCF PUT - JSON body to object

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

This is my first REST service, basically it is a self hosted service that is listening on a port for a PUT call which will have a payload of JSON data.  I want to convert that to a native object, I thought the serializer could do it automatically but it's not working.

This SO does work for me:  [WCF REST Service JSON Post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384303/wcf-rest-service-json-post-data)

I can get the JSON data as a stream and output it to a log just fine, but now I am wondering if WCF can automagically put the JSON data to my object.

The JSON data is this.

```
{
  "ID": 639073,
  "PatientFirst": "John",
  "PatientLast": "Smith",
  "Birthdate": "1/1/2000",
  "PtEmail":"rdejournett@medfusion.com",
  "Sex": "F",
  "mrn": ""
}
```

I have an ApptData class which is this.

```
[DataContract]
class ApptData {
    [DataMember]
    internal string ID = "";

    [DataMember]
    internal string PatientFirst = "";
    [DataMember]
    internal string PatientLast = "";
    [DataMember]
    internal string Birthdate = "";
    [DataMember]
    internal string PtEmail = "";
    [DataMember]
    internal string Sex = "";
    [DataMember]
    internal string mrn = "";

    public ApptData() { }
}
```

And the iContract is this.  I want to use the stuff that is commented out.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface iContract
{
    [OperationContract]


    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "CheckinPUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    //Stream PatientCheckinWithDemos(ApptData data);
    Stream PatientCheckinWithDemos(Stream streamdata);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for deserializing the JSON?  Even if it's not working? And out of curiousity, why are you using fields instead of properties?

Comment: That's basically my question, do I need to create code to deserialize it or is there a way to do it somewhat easily?

Comment: `do I need to create code to deserialize it or is there a way to do it somewhat easily?` No, Your commented interface is the right way to go and it should work. If I remember correctly, you should use `WebHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution wherein I do the deserializing.  It's not too hard.

Here is the class that impliments iContract.

```
    public Stream PatientCheckinWithDemos(Stream streamdata) {
        try {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ApptData));
            ApptData data = (ApptData)ser.ReadObject(streamdata);
            c.WriteToLog("Appt id is " + data.ID);
            c.WriteToLog("PatientFirst is " + data.PatientFirst);
            c.WriteToLog("PatientLast is " + data.PatientLast);
            c.WriteToLog("PtEmail is " + data.PtEmail);
            c.WriteToLog("Sex is " + data.Sex);
            c.WriteToLog("Birthdate is " + data.Birthdate);

            return GetStream("something");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.WriteToLog("Failure during Database Call to PatientCheckinWithDemos " + e.Message);
            return GetStream("");

        }
    }
```